# I can't connect to Mac with Xamarin Mac Agent from Visual Studio 2015

Tags: macos, debugging, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm continuing my adventure with Xamarin.

I'm developing an Xamarin Forms application with a Portable Class Libraries (PCL).

I have compiled and debugged my application by Android, but now, I'm interested to run the application in iOS to test in this platform.

I have a problem with the connection between my PC and the Mac.

I have a PC (Windows 8.1) with Visual Studio Community 2015 with Xamarin tools installed.

In my Mac Mini, I have installed OS X (v10.11.3), XCode (v7.2) and  Xamarin Studio. I have logged in with my Xamarin account.

In the two machines I have the same Xamarin version.

I have followed the [Xamarin walkthrough](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/).

On Visual Studio I open the Xamarin Mac Agent. It finds my Mac Mini. Then it asks me the Mac credentials (user and password).

[image]

The login works at this point.

[image]

Then, in the solution, I set the iOS project as the startup project. I clean the solution, I build again and start the compile/debug process (F5).

In this point, the output retrieves a message:

> 1>  Connecting to Mac server Macs-Mac-mini.local...
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Windows.After.targets(54,5): warning : Could not authenticate the user using the existing ssh keys
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Windows.After.targets(54,5): error : Unable to connect to Address='Macs-Mac-mini.local' with User='macmini

I have used Putty (SSH Client) to check with my user/password if I'm able to connect to Mac, and I have had success.

Into /Users/macmini2/.ssh/authorized_keys file (Mac machine) each time that I use the Xamarin Mac Agent, Visual Studio adds a new key entry (it adds the same repeated).

I see that perhaps the problem is related with ssh keys.
Why I have this problem? What am I doing wrong?

A thing that I have tested was openning the Xamarin project directly in Mac with Xamarin Studio, build it and run the simulator. It works.

I have seen other similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36514369/why-does-visual-studio-fail-to-connect-to-mac-agent-for-default-detected-mac-age), but I think that it doesn't have the same problem.

**EDIT:**

More specific information about the error when I try to compile/debug:

```
Could not authenticate the user using the existing ssh keys
Xamarin.Messaging.VisualStudio.MessagingAuthenticationException: Could not authenticate the user using the existing ssh keys ---> Renci.SshNet.Common.SshAuthenticationException: Permission denied (publickey).
   en Renci.SshNet.ClientAuthentication.Authenticate(IConnectionInfoInternal connectionInfo, ISession session)
   en Renci.SshNet.ConnectionInfo.Authenticate(ISession session)
   en Renci.SshNet.Session.Connect()
   en Renci.SshNet.BaseClient.Connect()
   en Xamarin.Messaging.VisualStudio.MessagingService.<ConnectAsync>d__70.MoveNext()
   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
```

**EDIT 2:**

I have revised the [troubleshooting Xamarin page](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting/#Unable_to_authenticate_with_SSH_keys._Please_try_to_log_in_with_credentials_first), specifically that it says "Unable to authenticate with SSH keys. Please try to log in with credentials first".

I have run:

```
chmod og-w "$HOME"
grep sshd /var/log/system.log > "$HOME/Desktop/sshd.log"
cd Desktop
cat sshd.log
```

And the content of the file is:

```
Apr 18 09:23:28 Macs-Mac-mini sshd[769]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /Users/macmini2/.ssh
Apr 18 09:25:27 Macs-Mac-mini com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.openssh.sshd.EE9A94ED-????-....-????-77254934B300[769]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
Apr 18 09:59:39 Macs-Mac-mini sshd[1036]: Accepted keyboard-interactive/pam for macmini2 from 192.168.54.14 port 60413 ssh2
Apr 18 09:59:39 Macs-Mac-mini sshd: macmini2 [priv][1036]: USER_PROCESS: 1040 ttys000
```

But now I don't know what I have to do to solve it.

Comment: It is the problem of SSH connection. Have you open the remote login on the Mac? have you try to connect the mac with other device by using SSH?

Comment: @XinMeng Yes, I think so. The problem is the SSH connection. I'm able to connect to Mac from my Windows with Putty (with user and password). The login works.

But I haven't tried to establish the ssh connection through the keys that generates the Xamarin Mac Agent. I don't know where are SSH keys to use in Putty to test it.

Comment: In my case: `Xcode is not installed. Please install it and try to reconnect or select another server to connect to.` But of course Xcode(9.0 beta 6) is installed. Can't ask a question(You have reached your question limit :( ). Someone, please help

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have found the solution about my problem. I have done the following steps:

1. **In my Windows:** I have removed the content from "%localappdata%\Xamarin\MonoTouch."
2. **In Mac terminal:** Remove the authorized_keys Mac file ("rm  /Users/macmini2/.ssh/authorized_keys" in my case)
3. **In Mac terminal:** chmod g-w /Users/macmini2/
4. **In Mac terminal:** chmod 700 /Users/macmini2/.ssh/
5. **In Mac terminal:** Create a empty file: /Users/macmini2/.ssh/authorized_keys (with vim, for example)
6. **In Mac terminal:** chmod 600 /Users/macmini2/.ssh/authorized_keys
7. **On Visual Studio:** Login with Xamarin Mac Agent
8. **On Visual Studio:** Run the application with [Debug] - [iPhoneSimulator] - [iPhone 5 iOS 8.1]
9. And finally, the simulator runs on Mac computer.

[This link](http://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2010/09/14/ssh-authentication-refused/) helped me.

Comment: About point 5 - since you are in terminal you can create file with "touch /Users/macmini2/.ssh/authorized_keys"

Comment: @BartoszStrutyński yes, you have reason. It's another way :-)

Comment: There is probably something wrong with my setup because I need to repeat those steps every time Xamarin or MacOSX updates. So thanks for those instructions ! I made a batch with them and it works like a charm :)

Comment: Sadly, these steps do not work for me at all.  Still the same manner of problem.  I followed EVERYTHING in the troubleshooting list and EVERYTHING listed here.  No joy. :(

Comment: @JohnTamburo If you gave us some clues about your problem, we could help you.

Comment: spent an hour trying all sorts of things, at first this didn't work either, after restarting mac and visual studio couple of times this finally worked

Comment: Its works for me by using the permission _chmod -R 755 /Users/test/.ssh_
Once connected you can reset back to 700 for the directory ..../ssh

Comment: deleting the contents of %localappdata%\Xamarin\MonoTouch seemed to be enough for me

Answer (score 36):

You have to try delete everything from

```
%localappdata%\Xamarin\MonoTouch
```

It helped me, I had the same (or similar) problem today.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I have tried your suggestion, but (for me) it doesn't work. I have removed the id_rsa files on the Windows directory that you specified and also I have removed the authorized_keys file in my Mac.

In the end of the public key file appears macmini2@Macs-Mac-mini.local, the ".local" I'm not sure if it's a correct format user/ur.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day.

Comment: Thank you so much! Followed your suggestion and get my similar issue resolved.

Comment: Instead of deleting I've just added my private and public keys in that folder. The ones that I've already added to the host machine (the Mac)

Answer (score 7):

Xamarin has a Troubleshooting page with large focus on SSH issues:

[Connection Troubleshooting](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting/)

Specifically these two:

**Log File Location**

```
Mac – ~/Library/Logs/Xamarin-[MAJOR.MINOR]
Windows – %LOCALAPPDATA%\Xamarin\Logs
```

The log files can be located by browsing to Help > Xamarin > Zip Logs in Visual Studio.

**"Unable to authenticate with SSH keys. Please try to log in with credentials first"**

Known cause:

```
SSH security restriction – This message most often means that one of the files or directories in the fully qualified path of $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys on the Mac has write permissions enabled for other or group members. Common fix: Run chmod og-w "$HOME" in a Terminal command prompt on the Mac. For details about which particular file or directory is causing the problem, run grep sshd /var/log/system.log > "$HOME/Desktop/sshd.log" in Terminal, and then open the sshd.log file from your Desktop and look for "Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes".
```

Furthermore there is this section, which does not directly match the error you are seeing but goes into some detail on SSH configuration and diagnosis:

**"Couldn't connect to MacBuildHost.local. Please try again."**

Reported causes:

```
Bug – A few users have seen this error message when attempting to log in to the build host using an Active Directory domain user account.

Bug – Some users have seen this error when attempting to connect to the build host by double-clicking the name of the Mac in the connection dialog. Possible workaround: Manually add the Mac using the IP address.

Bug #35971 – Some users have run across this error when using a wireless network connection between the Mac build host and Windows. Possible workaround: Move both computers to a wired network connection.

Bug #36642 – On Xamarin 4.0, this message will appear anytime the $HOME/.bashrc file on the Mac contains an error. (Starting with Xamarin 4.1, errors in the .bashrc file will no longer affect the connection process.) Workaround: Move the .bashrc file to a backup location (or delete it if you know you don't need it).

Limitation – This error can appear if the Mac build host is connected to a router that has no access to the internet (or if the Mac is using a DNS server that times out when asked for the reverse-DNS lookup of the Windows computer). Visual Studio will take roughly 30 seconds to retrieve the SSH fingerprint and eventually fail to connect.

Possible workaround: Add "UseDNS no" to the sshd_config file. Be sure to read about this SSH setting before changing it. See for example http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56941/what-is-the-point-of-sshd-usedns-option.

The following steps describe one way to change the setting. You will need to be logged in to an administrator account on the Mac to complete the steps.

    Confirm the location of the sshd_config file by running ls /etc/ssh/sshd_config and ls /etc/sshd_config in a Terminal command prompt. For all of the remaining steps, be sure to use the location that does not return "No such file or directory".

    Run cp /etc/ssh/sshd_config "$HOME/Desktop/" in Terminal to copy the file to your desktop.

    Open the file from your Desktop in a text editor. For example you can run open -a TextEdit "$HOME/Desktop/sshd_config" in Terminal.

    Add the following line at the bottom of the file:

    UseDNS no

    Remove any lines that say UseDNS yes to make sure the new setting takes effect.

    Save the file.

    Run sudo cp "$HOME/Desktop/sshd_config" /etc/ssh/sshd_config in Terminal to copy the edited file back into place. Enter your password if prompted.

    Disable and re-enable Remote Login under System Preferences > Sharing > Remote Login to restart the SSH server.
```

Comment: I have already seen previously this Xamarin entry, but I have revised again. I have followed the steps about "Unable to authenticate with SSH keys. Please try to log in with credentials first". I have obtained into sshd.log file the same error that they say. But now I don't know what I have to do to solve it.

Comment: I had to run `chmod og-w "$HOME"` in terminal on he Mac mentioned in the troubleshoot.

Answer (score 5):

I have just solved this problem!
It was nonsense.

To connect Visual Studio Xamarin project and simulate that on Mac when you get:

> Couldn't connect to computername.local please try again later.

What you need to do next:

1. Follow the solution from xamarin community about mac connection
   after this point if everything OK, you will connect, but if no..
2. Install XAMARIN STUDIO on MAC. After installation start XAMARIN studio, create your own app and run with simulator
3. Close app and try to connect again from Windows computer.
   At this point you will make synchronization and that's all.

Problem solved! I hope this will be useful for somebody.

Comment: do you have a link to the xamarin community solution?

Answer (score 4):

For me helped next solution:
1)On Windows open Visual Studio:
Tools=>Options=>Xamarin=>Other and click in Check Now

2)On Mac open Xamarin Studio Community (https://www.xamarin.com/download)
Xamarin Studio Community=>Check for Updates... (and download last one)

After updates all works fine.

Comment: Man! That's it! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I tried a few of the solutions mentioned here and had no success.

However (though not ideal) if I run Visual Studio in Administrator Mode I can successfully connect. Could be a work around for some until a better solution is found.

Comment: This should have been a comment rather than an answer

Comment: Reputation is not greater than 50 so I cannot comment.

Answer (score 2):

This is not perfect solution, but made success in my case

> Your mac account should not contain any special characters- This is limitation in connection to mac from windows

### company-mac1 --- wrong

### comapanymac1 --- Correct

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth I just solved this issue by checking the logs as noted above and in the Xamarin Troubleshooting docs. It turned out to be mismatched iOS versions. Once I updated the Mac version it worked.

[image]

Comment: This worked great for me. I had to go to Tools -> Options -> Xamarin to the iOS settings to fire up the Mac agent and get reconnected to the Mac, but got it working. I didn't have to remove anything from the Xamarin/Monotouch directory. It's very easy to forget to get the Mac side updated (I have to use Xamarin Studio there to do it, the Xamarin Installer doesn't seem to always get that part updated for me).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i installed mono sdk on my mac it solve the problem
http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-mac

Answer (score 1):

Ignored the agent that Visual Studio wizard showed. Something about the Mac computer name VS didn't understand.

I did 'Add Mac', used the IP address, then it connected. That was annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Did you turn on remote login and that is the user/login that is currently logged into the machine? Also, have you tried connecting directly to the IP address instead of the DNS name?

I am on a client's network (different domain than mine) and my VS would never connect via the computer name. I **always** had to type in the IP address. Also, watch the out put for "Xamarin" in the Output panel/window and see if it gives any more helpful information.

Comment: Hi @valdetero, I have tried with IP address. The first screenshot that I shared shows the IP address that my Mac has.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem recently (despite having enabled Sharing on the OSX host and checking firewall) and it turned out that both OSX Machine and Windows Machine needed the exact same version of Xamarin.iOS and a restart.

Updating both, restarting both, solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think what fixed it for me was opening `git bash` then running `ssh onto the mac box`.  After saying `Y` to `trusting credentials` it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I could not connect to XCode because "XCode" file wasn't located at the "Application" folder on MacOS. When the "XCode" app was moved to "Application" folder, I had connect.

Answer (score -1):

**Update Visual Studion on Mac and:**
**1) Delete on Mac - all files in .ssh (rm *)**
**2) Delete on Mac the folder .ssh**
3) On Windows, generate your ssh key and transfer to MAC - for that **Open Windows PowerShell** and execute the follow commands:
*[generate the key]*
`PS>ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096`

*[define the remote host variable]*
`PS>$REMOTEHOST="name_of_mac_user@ip_mac_machine"`

*[send the key to mac machine]*
`PS>scp "$env:USERPROFILE\.ssh\id_rsa.pub" "${REMOTEHOST}:~/tmp.pub"`

*[copy the key tmb.pub to authorized_keys file and set the permissions]*
`PS>ssh "$REMOTEHOST" "mkdir -p ~/.ssh && chmod 700 ~/.ssh && cat ~/tmp.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys && chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys && rm -f ~/tmp.pub"`

**4) check on mac .ssh folder if the authorized_keys file is correct:**
`tail ./authorized_keys`

**5) check the permission for authorized_keys (-rw-------)**
`ls -al ./authorized_keys`