# Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Can't connect to Xamarin after following all steps

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios

Running Windows 10 Enterprise, Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise.  Trying to connect to a Mac running El Capitan and the latest xCode.  The mac is named BigMac.  I can log into it using SSH.

I followed all of the steps in the Xamarin troubleshooting guide.  I also followed all of the steps in the accepted answer of this question.

[I can't connect to Mac with Xamarin Mac Agent from Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577546/i-cant-connect-to-mac-with-xamarin-mac-agent-from-visual-studio-2015)

Unfortunately that does not help.  Please see message and log below.

My thanks - heartfelt thanks - to anyone who can help me with this.

Thanks
John.

Message:
[image]

Here is the log:

```
Xamarin Information: 0 : [2016-07-12 11:05:35.2229] Xamarin - 4.1.1.3-c7sr0+34a92cd
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Activation.AccountManager Information: 0 : [2016-07-12 11:05:35.4416] VS2015 Enterprise
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ActivationManager Information: 0 : [2016-07-12 11:05:35.5041] No license found for iOS
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ActivationManager Information: 0 : [2016-07-12 11:05:35.5041] Running license sync for iOS
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ActivationManager Information: 0 : [2016-07-12 11:05:35.5197] No license found for Android
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ActivationManager Information: 0 : [2016-07-12 11:05:35.5353] Running license sync for Android
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ActivationManager Information: 0 : [2016-07-12 11:05:38.1445] Updated license: iOS VSEnterprise
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ActivationManager Information: 0 : [2016-07-12 11:05:38.1445] Updated license: Android VSEnterprise
Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyPackage Information: 0 : [2016-07-12 11:05:42.5352] Hooked up SDB tracing adapter
Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyPackage Information: 0 : [2016-07-12 11:05:42.5977] Initialization finished
Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.XamarinIOSPackage Warning: 0 : [2016-07-12 11:05:42.6133] Initializing Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.XamarinIOSPackage.
Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.XamarinIOSPackage Information: 0 : [2016-07-12 11:05:42.6289] MDAddinsHash: 33f406fa2dcf214012c78cb846585f062b2e1d24

Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Bonjour.BonjourDiscovery Information: 0 : [2016-07-12 11:05:50.0332] Bonjour service 'BigMac' did not respond with its IP address.
Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Messaging.State.ServerStateContext Information: 0 : [2016-07-12 11:06:05.1131] MacServer State transition from DisconnectedState to SshConnectingState on BigMac.local (10.64.0.141)
Xamarin.Messaging.VisualStudio.MessagingService Information: 0 : [2016-07-12 11:06:16.1937] Starting Broker 4.1.1.3 in port 55030...
Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Messaging.State.ServerStateContext Information: 0 : [2016-07-12 11:06:27.6814] MacServer State transition from SshConnectingState to DisconnectedState on BigMac.local (10.64.0.141)
Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Messaging.State.ServerStateContext Information: 0 : [2016-07-12 11:06:27.6914] Disconnected from Mac BigMac.local (10.64.0.141)
Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Messaging.State.DisconnectedState Error: 0 : [2016-07-12 11:06:27.7234] Couldn't connect to BigMac.local. Please try again.
Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Messaging.State.DisconnectedState Error: 0 : [2016-07-12 11:06:27.7404] The operation has timed out.
System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.
   at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.Ssh.BrokerCommands.<StartBrokerAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.Messaging.VisualStudio.MessagingService.<StartBrokerAsync>d__110.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Xamarin.Messaging.VisualStudio.MessagingService.<ConnectAsync>d__73.MoveNext()
Xamarin.Messaging.MacLogFileMessage Information: 0 : [2016-07-12 11:06:27.8474] Downloading /Users/johntam/Library/Logs/Xamarin-4.1/2016-07-12__11-05-42.1760.Broker.stderr.log...
```