# "Starting Mac agent: IDB 4.1.1.3 ..." was pending when connect to Mac with Xamarin Mac Agent from VS2015

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios

I tried to connect to Mac with Xamarin Mac Agent from VS2015. 
The network connection between mac & windows was ok, and I validated it with Step 8 [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting/#Known_Issues_and_Limitations)

I input user & password and connect, no feedback message. 
On Visual studio status bar, "Starting Mac agent: IDB 4.1.1.3 ..." was pending.

BTY, I can build Xamarin.IOS successfully, but can't run ios simulator from VS2015. And I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577546/i-cant-connect-to-mac-with-xamarin-mac-agent-from-visual-studio-2015), but no use for me.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced a similar issue when I updated xamarin on visual studio. I resolved this by:

1. Updating xamarin studio. Go to Xamarin Studio > Check for Updates
2. Deleting folders `%localappdata%/Xamarin/MonoTouch` from my windows machine and `$HOME/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs` folder from my mac.
3. Restarting both xamarin and visual studio.