# Connecting Visual Studio (w Xamarin) to Mac

Tags: networking, xamarin, ssh, visual-studio-2015, sshd

I have a fully set-up Mac with OSX 10.11 with all the necessary to run Xamarin for iOS.
I've installed on a Windows 10 laptop Visual Studio 2015 and got the following error:

> Unable to authenticate with ssh keys. Please try to log in with credentials first

Then I've installed on a W7 PC VS2015, same up to date version of the laptop, and tried the same connection, under the same network: works flawlessly.
Everything is form the stable channel.
The firewall on the laptop, like on the other PC allows Xamarin to comunicate on LAN.
From the laptop and the PC I can remotely login via ssh the Mac in less than a second.

Here's the log from the laptop:

```
Xamarin Information: 0 : [2017-01-23 21:54:24.1947] Xamarin - 4.2.2.11-cycle8+00fa5cc
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Activation.AccountManager Information: 0 : [2017-01-23 21:54:24.4013] VS2015 Community
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ActivationManager Information: 0 : [2017-01-23 21:54:24.6238] No license found for iOS
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ActivationManager Information: 0 : [2017-01-23 21:54:24.7790] Running license sync for iOS
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ActivationManager Information: 0 : [2017-01-23 21:54:24.9327] Not logged in, using iOS Community
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ActivationManager Information: 0 : [2017-01-23 21:54:25.1185] No license found for Android
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ActivationManager Information: 0 : [2017-01-23 21:54:25.2981] Running license sync for Android
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ActivationManager Information: 0 : [2017-01-23 21:54:25.4847] Not logged in, using Android Community
Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyPackage Information: 0 : [2017-01-23 21:54:25.7654] Hooked up SDB tracing adapter
Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyPackage Information: 0 : [2017-01-23 21:54:25.9455] Initialization finished
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.XamarinAndroidPackage Warning: 0 : [2017-01-23 21:54:26.1277] Initializing Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.XamarinAndroidPackage
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.Designer.MonoAndroidDesignerService Warning: 0 : [2017-01-23 21:54:26.6038] An unexpected error occurred trying to initialize Android Designer.
Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyPackage Information: 0 : [2017-01-23 21:54:37.7048] Hooked up SDB tracing adapter
Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyPackage Information: 0 : [2017-01-23 21:54:37.8834] Initialization finished
Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.XamarinIOSPackage Warning: 0 : [2017-01-23 21:54:38.0746] Initializing Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.XamarinIOSPackage.
Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.XamarinIOSPackage Information: 0 : [2017-01-23 21:54:38.2597] MDAddinsHash: c92d0626d347aaa02839689eaac2961d24c9f446

Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Bonjour.BonjourDiscovery Information: 0 : [2017-01-23 21:54:40.8859] Bonjour service 'Gian iMac' did not respond with its IP address.
Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Messaging.State.ServerStateContext Information: 0 : [2017-01-23 21:54:58.6464] MacServer State transition from DisconnectedState to SshConnectingState on Gian-iMac.local (192.168.1.100)
Xamarin.Messaging.VisualStudio.MessagingService Information: 0 : [2017-01-23 21:55:09.3709] Starting connection to Mac Gian-iMac.local...
Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Messaging.State.DisconnectedState Error: 0 : [2017-01-23 21:55:16.7865] Unable to authenticate with SSH keys. Please try to log in with credentials first
Xamarin.Messaging.VisualStudio.Exceptions.MessagingAuthenticationException: Could not authenticate the user 'gianventotto' with SSH keys. Please check that both $HOME folder and ~/.ssh/authorized_keys have the appropiate permissions to use SSH. More details: Permission denied (publickey). ---> Renci.SshNet.Common.SshAuthenticationException: Permission denied (publickey).
   in Renci.SshNet.ClientAuthentication.Authenticate(IConnectionInfoInternal connectionInfo, ISession session)
   in Renci.SshNet.ConnectionInfo.Authenticate(ISession session, IServiceFactory serviceFactory)
   in Renci.SshNet.Session.Connect()
   in Renci.SshNet.BaseClient.Connect()
   in Xamarin.Messaging.Client.Ssh.SshMessagingConnection.ConnectSsh()
   in Xamarin.Messaging.VisualStudio.MessagingService.<ConnectAsync>d__71.MoveNext()
   --- Fine della traccia dello stack dell'eccezione interna ---
Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Messaging.State.DisconnectedState Error: 0 : [2017-01-23 21:55:17.1607] Unable to authenticate with SSH keys. Please try to log in with credentials first
Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Messaging.State.ServerStateContext Information: 0 : [2017-01-23 21:55:17.3478] MacServer State transition from SshConnectingState to DisconnectedState on Gian-iMac.local (192.168.1.100)
Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Messaging.State.ServerStateContext Information: 0 : [2017-01-23 21:55:17.5335] Disconnected from Mac Gian-iMac.local (192.168.1.100)
```

And here's the corresponding Mac `sshd` log:

```
Jan 23 21:54:49 DellGian sshd[432]: Invalid user a from fe80::684c:a641:25d5:499a%en1
Jan 23 21:54:49 DellGian sshd[432]: input_userauth_request: invalid user a [preauth]
Jan 23 21:54:49 DellGian sshd[432]: Connection closed by fe80::684c:a641:25d5:499a%en1 [preauth]
Jan 23 21:54:49 DellGian com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.openssh.sshd.B87D7BAE-892F-4EB8-91E9-FD74A3B0C534[432]): Service exited with abnormal code: 255
Jan 23 21:55:06 DellGian sshd[434]: Accepted keyboard-interactive/pam for gianventotto from fe80::684c:a641:25d5:499a%en1 port 54361 ssh2
Jan 23 21:55:08 DellGian sshd[438]: Accepted keyboard-interactive/pam for gianventotto from fe80::684c:a641:25d5:499a%en1 port 54366 ssh2
Jan 23 21:55:09 DellGian sshd[437]: Received disconnect from fe80::684c:a641:25d5:499a%en1: 11: Connection terminated by the client.
Jan 23 21:55:09 DellGian sshd[437]: Disconnected from fe80::684c:a641:25d5:499a%en1
Jan 23 21:55:09 DellGian com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.openssh.sshd.3A1CBE22-0A14-479F-AB4B-47981092D26C[434]): Service exited with abnormal code: 255
Jan 23 21:55:09 DellGian sshd[441]: Received disconnect from fe80::684c:a641:25d5:499a%en1: 11: Connection terminated by the client.
Jan 23 21:55:09 DellGian sshd[441]: Disconnected from fe80::684c:a641:25d5:499a%en1
Jan 23 21:55:09 DellGian com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.openssh.sshd.0EEDF8CA-4DBF-4EF5-BCC8-00CF25C16C83[438]): Service exited with abnormal code: 255
Jan 23 21:55:28 DellGian sshd[445]: Connection reset by fe80::684c:a641:25d5:499a%en1 [preauth]
Jan 23 21:55:28 DellGian com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.openssh.sshd.486B5640-1C66-40F0-AFEC-44D3C54C39E9[445]): Service exited with abnormal code: 255
```

Shouldn't I just use the PC? Nope, it needs almost 10 min to start Visual Studio!
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Try to open a ssh session from Windows to Mac from the command line to see if this works.

Comment: @apineda It works, I thought I've written it

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your Win 10 laptop has ssh keys in place for passwordless login, and perhaps (or not) that key was added to your `authorized_keys` file on your Mac at `~/.ssh` (shortcut for `/Users/<username>/.ssh`) , but that the login with the ssh keys is not working, perhaps due to permissions issues. Relevant line of log above:

> Xamarin.Messaging.VisualStudio.Exceptions.MessagingAuthenticationException: Could not authenticate the user 'gianventotto' with SSH keys. Please check that both $HOME folder and ~/.ssh/authorized_keys have the appropiate permissions to use SSH. More details: Permission denied (publickey). ---> Renci.SshNet.Common.SshAuthenticationException: Permission denied (publickey).

Maybe try removing your Win 10 ssh key from the `authorized_keys` file on your Mac and log in from VS using your username and password instead?

Comment: It sounds like the solution provided here http://stackoverflow.com/a/36689556/5313090, that I've already tried out without success, but this time has worked! Maybe because I've deleted the swap file too?