# Unable to generate SSH keys for the User in Xamarin Mac Agent

Tags: ios, xamarin, ssh

I have a High Sierra Mac and a Windows 10 Laptop. I am struggling to connect to the Xamarin Mac Agent from my laptop.
I can SSH into my Mac from my laptop using PuTTY and OpenSSH Beta. I have the port open at the router and I can SSH into my mac from my local network and over the internet.

When I try to connect using Xamarin Mac Agent I get an unable to generate SSH keys for the user message. I get it when selecting my Mac explicitly from the list or adding the local IP address and the global IP address.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you enabled the SSH on the mac from System Preferences > Sharing ?

Comment: It is enabled, yes.

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/77655/xamarin-mac-agent-wont-connect   may help.

Answer (score 1):

you have to delete everything from this file

```
%localappdata%\Xamarin\MonoTouch
```

[I can't connect to Mac with Xamarin Mac Agent from Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577546/i-cant-connect-to-mac-with-xamarin-mac-agent-from-visual-studio-2015) 
this link might help

Comment: Was stuck with ungooglable "cannot create file already existing systemio exception", that solved it