# Xamarin.IOS Unable to connect to Mac Server with Address

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I've just updated visual studio 2019 to the latest build (16.9.4) and now my xamarin.ios won't deploy to the simulator. We're receiving the following error:

```
Unable to connect to Mac Server with Address='192.168.0.94' and User='My user'. The build can't continue without a connection   MyApp.Mobile.iOS
```

Nothing has changed other then the VS update and have tried on another dev's computer and it's doing the same thing after update. Everything has been updated on the mac side as well to match the VS update.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the IP address? Maybe there's some change of it.

Comment: Also, on macOS, double check the user account name in the /User/ folder; sometimes it doesn't match the name that is displayed on the macOS login UI.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

1)On Windows open Visual Studio: Tools=>Options=>Xamarin=>Other and click in Check Now

2)On Mac open Xamarin Studio Community (https://www.xamarin.com/download) Xamarin Studio Community=>Check for Updates... (and download last one)

After updates check if it works fine. If it still doesn't work then try to delete everything from

**%localappdata%\Xamarin\MonoTouch**

For more information you can checkout [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36689556/9218131).

Comment: Looks like cleaning `%localappdata%\Xamarin\MonoTouch` helped